# Change SCSS File Watcher to only start after saving in PhpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have configured SCSS File Watcher in PhpStorm and it works without problems. The only point disturbing me, it start every time shortly after I start writing. Coming from Netbeans I am used to save my change and only then file watchers are starting. Is there any know way to archive such behaviour in PhpStorm?

To make it clear: File Watcher is working, there are no problems like "is not triggering", "file not found" or something else. I only want a similar behaviour to how I know it from Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it with the following tweaks:

- Deselect the **Immediate file synchronization** check box.
- Select check box to have the File Watcher started upon save ( File
  | Save All for Windows and Unix or PhpStorm | Save All for OS X ) or
  when you move focus from PhpStorm (upon frame deactivation).

You can find more filewatcher in-depth info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/using-file-watchers.html)